# Invalid subscript type 'list' in k modes in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a dataset with 8848 observations with 46 variables.While applying kmodes for the required columns it is giving error.

I tried like below

```
library(klaR)
Data_Value <- read.csv("Path", header=TRUE)
var1<-subset(Data_Value,Data_Value$Improvement=="Improved")
var2<-subset(Data_Value,Data_Value$Improvement=="Not Improved")
data<-rbind(var1,var2[1:4424,])
clustering<-(data[c(2,3,30,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46)])
kmodes(na.omit(clustering),5, iter.max = 10,weighted = TRUE)
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error in `[.default`(weights[[j]], sapply(as.character(modes[, j]), function(z) return(which(names(weights[[j]]) ==  : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

When i used 33 column in the data it is giving above error.please,suggest me where am i gone wrong?

dput(head(clustering,5)):

```
structure(list(column2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Adult", 
"Child", "Infant"), class = "factor"), column3 = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ALK", "DALK", "EK", "Others", "PK", 
"THPK"), class = "factor"), column30 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Improved", "Not Improved"), class = "factor"), 
  column32 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), column33 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), column34= c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column35 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column36 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column37 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),column38 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),column39 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column40 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column41 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column42 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),column43 = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), column44 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE),column45 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE), column46= c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: something might be weird about your data frame Data_Value. If I simulate data, do na.omit and kmodes, it works. Can you do dput(head(clustering,20)) and paste that as part of your question?

Comment: Thank you for responding @StupidWolf, I included head of data,Please look through it.

Comment: Hi @Magie, thanks for putting the data. It still doesn't make sense for me. The result you pasted from dput(head(clustering,10)) gives 5 rows instead of 10. And you are trying to use kmodes on variables that are either factors or binary?

Comment: Sorry that is type mistake.Actually, i.e, ```dput(head(clustering,5))```

Comment: I have mixed data type variables i.e, factors and logical

Comment: Can we do kmodes cluster if mixed data types present in the data?

Comment: In this case I think it's ok. can you change this clustering<-(data[c(2,3,30,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46)]) to clustering<-(data[,c(2,3,30,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46)])

Comment: or did you load dplyr?

Comment: I got same error.I didn't use dplyr package in this code.

Comment: Hi @Magie, I don't get your error when I run kmodes on the example. Something must have gone wrong in the data processing and I cannot tell just from the example or code you've provided